# Internal Server error 500 in Tomcat log - Problem with x-forwarded-for header

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, reverse-proxy, nat, sapb1

I need to configure external access for a service based on SAP Business One. The service in this example is a Mobile service so one can use a mobile app provided by SAP.

In order to use the app, the URL needs to be externally accessible. We want to use Sophos WAF (Web Application Firewall) as a reverse proxy to make it accessible from an external source.

The problem is the following:

External access with NAT and a specific port works however external access with the Sophos WAF as the reverse proxy fails. We get a HTTP ERROR 500 when trying to access the URL.
In the tomcat logs of the SAP Server I could find this extra information:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: None of SP's internal [`https://sapinternal:port/service/`] and external address [`https://sapextern.domain.com:port/service`] haven't been found in value of the "x-forwarded-for" header [public ip-address of the client].

Any advice on how to resolve this or why this error appears when using Sophos WAF instead of NAT is appreciated.